# Save session data in a PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session

In a php page I'm getting values and I can save it like follows:

```
<?php
 session_start();
// store session data
$_SESSION['advert']=8;
?>
```

and retrieve it like follows:

```
<?php
   //retrieve session data
   echo "advertID=". $_SESSION['advert'];
?>
```

and I can retrieve the value as 8 later.

But I need to save three product value IDs in a PHP array in a search session and later I need to retrieve them and connect them with the database(my SQL) to build up a compare table among those three products. How can I save three values in a PHP array and retrieve them later in a PHP session?

And if try to save more IDs:

- 4th ID should be replaced with the first value in the array
- 5th ID should be replaced with the second value in the array
- 6th ID should be replaced with the third value in the array and goes like that..

Comment: Just... put them in an array and store that in the session...? What's the problem?

Comment: i haven't used php session and arrays for this kind of task earlier so i'm bit confused.

Comment: Then explain in more detail what exactly you're confused about.

Comment: if i need to add more values than three can we replace earlier values with new values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['products'])) {
    $_SESSION['products'] = array();
}

// add new product
$_SESSION['products'][] = $productId;

// trim array down to a maximum of three
$_SESSION['products'] = array_slice($_SESSION['products'], -3);
```

This way you keep a [FIFO list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO) of the last three products.

Answer (score 1):

Method 1:
(just save values to session variables if you have small number of variables like 3.)

```
$_SESSION['var1'] = "value1";
$_SESSION['var2'] = "value2";
$_SESSION['var3'] = "value3";
```

Method 2:
(using arrays)

```
$array = array();
$array['var1'] = "value1";
$array['var2'] = "value2";
$array['var3'] = "value3";

$_SESSION['array_values'] = $array;
```

when you want to replace:

1. just repeat the method
2. Or use `$_SESSION['array_values']['var#'] = "value#";`

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrSession = array();
$arrSession[] = 'Value1';
$arrSession[] = 'Value2';
$arrSession[] = 'Value3';


$_SESSION['search'] = $arrSession;

//Retrive it as $_SESSION['search'] whereever necessary
```

Comment: if i need to replace the values in the array what can i do?